# Creating django api view that returns filtered objects

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

**Problem Description**
I'm new to django-rest-framework and got a problem in my view. I have three models namely #User, #Profession and #StudentProfessions. I need to create an api-view that takes user_id as request-parameter and returns a list of all professions that belongs to a particular user_id.

**Here's My Codes**

**profession_app >> models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Profession(models.Model):
    profession_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.profession_name
```

**User Model**

I used the django default model.

**student_profile_app >> models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from department_app.models import Department
from profession_app.models import Profession
from program_app.models import Program
from django.db import models

class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    student_status = models.BooleanField()
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    year_of_study = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    program_id = models.ForeignKey(Program, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student_id = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="student_id")
    organization_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="organization_id")
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    field_supervisor_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="field_supervisor")
    department_id = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    academic_supervisor_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="academic_supervisor")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.student_id.username } Profile'


class StudentProfession(models.Model):
    student_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="student_profession_id")
    profession_id = models.ForeignKey(Profession, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.student_id.username } Profession'
```

**student_profile_app >> views.py**

```
from .models import StudentProfile, StudentProfession

def getStudentProfessions(request, studentId):
    professions = StudentProfession.objects.filter(student_id=studentId)
    return professions
```

**And In My urls**

```
from student_profile_app.views import getStudentProfessions
from rest_framework import routers

router.register('getStudentProfessions/<int:studentId>', getStudentProfessions, 'getStudentProfessions')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

**But when i run the server i got the following error**

```
    urlpatterns = router.urls
  File "E:\Codes\FIP\fipEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\routers.py", line 77, in urls
    self._urls = self.get_urls()
  File "E:\Codes\FIP\fipEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\routers.py", line 338, in get_urls
    urls = super().get_urls()
  File "E:\Codes\FIP\fipEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\routers.py", line 236, in get_urls
    routes = self.get_routes(viewset)
  File "E:\Codes\FIP\fipEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\routers.py", line 152, in get_routes
    extra_actions = viewset.get_extra_actions()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all ***StudentProfession.student_id*** has bad model parameter set (its related to ***User*** model - it should be ***Student*** model).

Django rest framework uses viewset's for routers.
What you need is [serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializers) which will represent your endpoint api structure and [viewset](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewsets).

I will write simple serializer and viewset for you but you really need to read docs.

***After edits from comments:***

Serializer class:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
#...other imports

class StudentProfessionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = StuedentProfession
        fields = ('profession')
```

Viewset class (that's what you register in router !)

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, mixins
#...other imports

class StudentProfessionViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet,
                               mixins.ListModelMixin,
                               mixins.RetrieveModelMixin):
    serializer_class = StudentProfessionSerializer
    queryset = StudentProfession.objects

    def get_queryset(self):
        student_id = self.kwargs.get('studentId')
        return self.queryset.filter(student_id=student_id)
```

Some tips from me:

- [READ DOCS](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/)
- you dont need to write "_id" suffix in ForeignKey fields (django make it automatically underhood - means that columns in your table will have _id suffix anyway) and then you can use params without this ugly _id... like this

  ```
   StudentProfession.objects.filter(student=somestudentid)
  ```
- your API should be constructed like

  ```
   router.register(r'students/(?P<studentId>\d+)/professions', StudentProfessionViewSet, 'student-profession')
  ```
- try not to use "real" ID's of objects in url - use UUID's instead - its safer

Comment: I did as instructed in your answer, and now the error comes in url patterns,   **Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/students/15/professions**. Just tried to retrieve all professions of student with id #15. What could be the cause of this error?

Comment: It Says ** Page Not Found**

Comment: Do you add your router urlpatterns in main project urls.py file ?

Comment: Yah, and other url patterns are working well, except this one.

Comment: Hmmm, try to use "localhost:8000/api/students/15/professions/" (added slash at the end of url)

Comment: I also edited the answer: in get_queryset method it should be self.kwargs.get('studentId')

Comment: I think i found the problem - url should be r'students/(?P<studentId>\d+)/professions' (this variable like <str:somevariable> can be used only in djagno Path objects). Post is edited with this solution.

Comment: Okay, Thank You. Now It Works Fine. But i made small modifications in the return statement of the get_queryset(), just removed the **studentprofession_set__** in the filter and the statement becomes **return self.queryset.filter(student_id=student_id)**. That's all .Could you edit again the statement in your answer for this small changes??. Thanks Again For Your Cooperation.

Comment: Hmm but it should not work, you dont have "student_id" field in your Profession model.

Comment: i do have it, from the **StudentProfession** model. This is where results come from, and not from **Profession** model. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: So the serializer should be **StudentProfessioSerializer**, and the corresponding model should be **StudentProfession**. That's it.